# How to Refresh current page in Webview on reception of push notification

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, android-webview

I have integrated webview & notification in my app. When notification is received in foreground, it shows Toast while in background it shows push notification.

I want two things for app to do when notification received:

1. Foreground: Refresh current page.
2. Background: on click on notification redirect to specific link.

Note: Firebase used for notification

> Below is webview code:

```
        mWebview =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        mWebview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

`EventBus` can meet your requirements,you can go to understand its usage.

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Register the Activity of the WebView,and create a method.

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Click the notification to send the message,will callback onMessageEvent.

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Comment: can you provide an example? code is much appreciated

Comment: You can refresh webview on the `onMessageEvent`.

Comment: dude I'm super new to android, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Register Broadcast Receiver in Activity and send Braodcast from Firebase web service and receive it in Activity to update webview

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                    "update_webview");

            mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    //extract our message from intent
                    String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("some_msg");
                    //log our message value


                }
            };
            //registering our receiver
            this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            //unregister our receiver
            this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
        }

Now send Braodcast from FCM  service where your received notification 

Intent i = new Intent("update_webview").putExtra("some_msg", "I will be sent!");
            this.sendBroadcast(i);
```